# Конвертация сайта в приложение

Tags: php, android, swift

Встречаю онлайн сервисы на PHP, которые позволяют указать ссылку на сайт и получить мобильное приложение с webview компонентом с предустановленным сайтом.
Как это работает? Какие библиотеки и механизмы используются? Буду рад ссылкам на статьи, раскрываюущую эту тему

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Механизм очень простой - Сайт-Мобильное приложение это Webview с привязанной главной страницей сайта.

Вот мануал как это сделать на Android Studio
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

По сути все что нужно сделать - это подготовить стандартный проект, а затем менять в нем только URL сайта и имя пакета (может еще что-то вылезти, но тут тестировать надо) и отдавать пользователю собранный пакет.

Заменить в файлах 2 строки можно любым по сути языком, скомпилировать тоже, используя командную строку https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Ну и естественно сервисы еще встраивают туда рекламу :).

Answer (score 0):

Занимался этим когда то, могу сказать что использовать сервисы не стоит, там и реклама, и лимиты свои (если не платить).

Решил этот вопрос легко: скачал Android Studio > посмотрел уроки как сделать WebView со своей ссылкой > скомпилировал приложение  > имитация мобильной версии как отдельное приложение - сработало, люди говорили что выглядит красиво.

Как это делается на iOS не знаю, но думаю что там все гораздо сложнее.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Меня интересует вопрос, как выполнить все это без ручного труда - в автоматическм режиме. Как то делают же это)